# Running Python file in Java program

Tags: java, python

I'm on a semantic project that needs to tokenize the given sentence into words. My opinion is that can be done very easily in python. But I'm familiar with the Jena Framework which is for Java. So I need any way to run python file in java and channelize the outputs to variables in java.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Jython](http://www.jython.org/).

Jython is an implementation of Python written in pure Java, and **seamlessly integrated with the Java platform**.  It thus allows you to run Python on any Java platform.